# Git pull with www-data permissions

Tags: git

I have a git repository that has dev, test and staging branches that get pulled to a vhost on a server.  I need to be able to git pull on the server using my user account but for the files that are pulled to be owned by the www-data user (and group).   When I used svn I could sudo as www-data and svn update with the --username --password options which would authenticate against svn as my user but maintain the correct file ownership.  Is there any way to do this with git (I actually use ssh keys rather than a password for authentication).

Comment: Actually, on re-reading your question something isn't clear to me. *Which* files need to be owned by this user and group? The 'real' files that are under version control, Git's files in the `.git` directory, or both? If you're trying to serve a website from a Git repository, you only need the 'real' files to have that user; if you're trying to share the repository, or allow access to the repository over HTTP, you need Git's files to have that user.

Answer (score 6):

You want to set this option on the repository you're pulling into (extract from `git help config`):

```
  core.sharedRepository
       When group (or true), the repository is made shareable between several
       users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are
       group-writable). When all (or world or everybody), the repository will
       be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable. When
       umask (or false), git will use permissions reported by umask(2). When
       0xxx, where 0xxx is an octal number, files in the repository will have
       this mode value.  0xxx will override user’s umask value (whereas the
       other options will only override requested parts of the user’s umask
       value). Examples: 0660 will make the repo read/write-able for the
       owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to group
       unless umask is e.g.  0022).  0640 is a repository that is
       group-readable but not group-writable. See git-init(1). False by
       default.
```

To set this option, `cd` to the working tree or repository that needs to have the right group/mode (not the origin repository you want to pull from), and run `git config core.sharedRepository group`. It doesn't just set the mode for files in the repository, it also makes sure they are all owned by the group that owns the root of the repository. The option takes effect whether you're working locally in the repository or pushing into it from another repository (e.g. via the `git://` protocol).

If you've already created files in the repository with the wrong owner and/or mode by not having this option set, you'll first need to `cd` into the repository and run`chmod -R g+rw .` and `chgrp -R www-data .` to get it into a consistent state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The main problem I have with doing that is that I don;t have any access to the git repository itself as it's located on a third parties infrastructure.  I am looking at moving this all to GitHub but I don;t know if that will make my life easier or not.

Comment: Don't forget that in Git, every working copy has its own repository: *repository* doesn't mean *upstream*. You only need this setting on the repository that you want to have the right group/mode. You **don't** need to do anything to the origin repository you pull from.